# Is there anyway to pause the Open Layers update thread?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm seeing issues with regards to request/response performance in Chrome when there are a large amount of polyline features in a vector source.  I've noticed that this problem disappears if I set the source layer to setVisible(false).  The preferred approach here would be to not have to hide the layer but instead stop the update thread from running for a moment while the ajax response is processed.  Does this sound like a viable approach and is it possible to do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by overloading the current map renderer and adding a property to support pausing the renderer.  For posterity, I've posted the code to do so below.  There's probably a better way to do this such as implementing a renderer and then setting the map renderer to use the new custom renderer however, this works for my purposes.

```
//custom OpenLayers pauseRenderer method
ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.pauseRenderer = function(pause){
    this.pauseRenderer_ = pause;
}

//custom OpenLayers map renderer to allow for pausing when needed
ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.renderFrameSuper = ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.renderFrame;
ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.renderFrame = function(frameState) {

    if(this.pauseRenderer_)
        return;

    this.renderFrameSuper(frameState);
};
```

Comment: Just for the record, it is likely that you just have the regular performance issues which are easy to fix. Here is one of many answers on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48637645/304179

Comment: Unfortunately, I had read those posts previously and they didn't help with the issues we were seeing.  The above however did fix this issue.